# AVPlayer bright on iPad 2

Tags: video, avplayer, brightness, ipad-2

AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayer have extra brightness on iPad2. This does not show up in 1 or sim. I am digging through the docs and working on finding a fix even if I have to use a cheap one. I've found various MPMoviePlayer fixes that say "use AVPlayer", so I did... but if anyone sees this question and has the same issue... well know will at least get 2 videos playing!

I'm still digging, right now, on this site and anywhere I can to find a fix, but AVPlayer is also the name of a commercial program so it's hard. If anyone has found this, please let me know. Otherwise, the best hack. I have to get back to testing my hacks for this...

and I am not new, I've read the manuals and adapted the AVPlayer to work inside its own view. Asking Apple for help usually results in tutorials, instead of believing they really don't finish sentences in the docs.

The player plays, responds to notifications, etc... just to let you know I really do know how to code. (I just make it a note to mention that customer service until they treat their customers right)

Comment: Found a hack using layers... doesn't fix it completely. Create a layer, set frame to video frame, position to pos, choose a dark color and change opacity. This isn't a fix, nor is it universal for everything, but works if you tweak the alpha's

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS4 on iPad 2, and has been fixed in iOS 5.